# AWS Cloudfront function modify m3u8 response body

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudfront, httpresponse, http-live-streaming, m3u8

> #EXTM3U
> #EXT-X-VERSION:5
> #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="JKX001-mp4a_96000_eng=2.m3u8",GROUP-ID="audio-AACL-96",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,CHANNELS="2"
> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=456455,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=414959,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=480x270,FRAME-RATE=25.000,AUDIO="audio-AACL-96"
> JKX001-avc1_300000=1.m3u8

I need to modify the HTTP response body of the m3u8 response that I am getting when someone hits my CloudFront. From m3u8 body above, I'd like to replace "JKX001" to to other string such as "AAA".
Then m3u8 response in body will be like

> #EXTM3U
> #EXT-X-VERSION:5
> #EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,URI="AAA-mp4a_96000_eng=2.m3u8",GROUP-ID="audio-AACL-96",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,CHANNELS="2"
> #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=456455,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=414959,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=480x270,FRAME-RATE=25.000,AUDIO="audio-AACL-96"
> AAA-avc1_300000=1.m3u8

Does CloudFront function has capability to do this ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this using the `Lambda at Edge` feature of Cloudfront.

In essence `Lambda at Edge` allows you to modify all aspects of the HTTP response at the time of the request or at the time of the response, using a Lambda function written in your language of choice. This lambda will run for EACH response, so the lambda execution cost should be considered. This is a program-it-yourself solution rather than a built-in text substitution feature.

Documentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html

As an alternative to `Lambda at Edge`, you might also consider whether it would be more practical to implement a dynamic web server that constructs the response body m3u8 using a templating approach.

Comment: My understanding is lamdba at edge doesn't have access to response body so you cannot rewrite it

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-updating-http-responses.html

> When you're working with the HTTP response, Lambda@Edge does not expose the body that is returned by the origin server to the origin-response trigger. You can generate a static content body by setting it to the desired value, or remove the body inside the function by setting the value to be empty.